# C++ Calling a destructor without freeing memory

Tags: c++

Let's say that for whatever reason I wanted to call the destructor on an object without freeing memory. I understand this is doable with `obj->~Type()`, but let's say I have a `void*` and don't know the type statically. I guess then I would need 2 pointers, one for the object and one for the destructor.

However, I am curious if it is possible to get away with just one pointer in this case. Let's say that I can guarantee that the object will have a virtual destructor, and it will derive at most from one base class. Is it possible to reach the destructor through the v-table? And is that doable in a standard-compliant way (probably not)?

Comment: Your approach looks ok to me. It will be good to see actual code to be sure.

Comment: Portable way? Absolutely not. A way that works on your particular implementation? Possibly, depending on how it lays out its vtables. If you care this much about run-time performance, you should be willing to trade some compile time for it (use templates so you're not stuck with `void*`s).

Comment: Do you mean that each object is derived from one base class ( no MI) or that all objects share the same base class (so `void*` is the wrong type)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why have a C++ object if you want to manage its memory independent of the object?

Comment: @MSalters I mean no MI and no virtual inheritance, as I suspect this would mess up any v-table solution. They don't have a common base class.

Comment: You say it "will derive at most from one base class" but then you say "They don't have a common base class". This seems like a direct conflict.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "at most from one" I mean any (one) or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the address of a destructor. Quote from the C++17 standard:

> The address of a destructor shall not be taken.

— See [C++17 Latest Draft](https://wg21.link/n4659), [class.dtor]/2.

#### Solution with two pointers

However your two-pointer approach works. See the following example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/X60koP)):

```
class Apple {};


struct Destructor {
public:
    template <class T>
    Destructor (const T* object) :
        object (object),
        dtor   ([] (const void* o) { static_cast<const T*> (o)->~T (); })
    {
    }

    void Call ()
    {
        dtor (object);
    }

private:
    const void*  object;
    void (*dtor) (const void*);
};


int main ()
{
    Apple* a = new Apple ();

    Destructor d (a);
    d.Call ();
}
```

The idea is taken from Herb Sutter's [blog post](https://herbsutter.com/2016/09/25/to-store-a-destructor/). Remark: the memory pointed to by `a` is not freed in my example.

For the above to work you will have to know type `Apple` statically when you store the destructor. This is done when `d` is constructed. The type `Apple` is passed to the ctor. through template parameter `T`.

But you do not have to know `Apple` when you destroy it with `d.Call ()`.

#### Solution with std::function

You can just as well call the destructor from an `std::function`.

```
#include <functional>

class Apple {};


int main ()
{
    Apple* a = new Apple ();

    std::function<void ()> d = [=] () { a->~Apple (); };
    d ();
}
```

Basically this does the same thing, as the previous approach. The pointer `a` is captured by the lambda, so it knows which `Apple` to destroy.

As previously when you are creating `d` you have to know `Apple`. It is in the lambda. If you call `d ()`, you do not have to know the type.

#### Solution with one pointer (using a common base class)

```
struct Fruit { virtual ~Fruit () {} };
struct Apple : Fruit {};
```

Obviously you can call a dtor. of an `Apple` through a `Fruit*` pointer, if `Fruit::~Fruit` is `virtual` (otherwise it is [UB](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.delete#3)). Similarly to the two-pointer solution, when you construct an object of `Apple` to be stored and destroyed later, you have to know the type (`Fruit* f = new Apple ()`), and when you destroy it, you do not have to know it (`f->~Fruit ()`).

Here `f` is a single pointer, but ends up using a second pointer, the vfptr (i.e. virtual function pointer), which points to an array of function pointers, one of which is the pointer to `~Apple`. So three pointers are dereferenced for `f->~Fruit ()`:

- `f`,
- the vfptr,
- the pointer to `~Apple`.

#### Solution with one pointer (no common base class)

It is impossible. Calling a destructor is a `call` instruction in assembly. For this you have to have two pointers:

- the argument to pass (the `this` pointer), and
- the address to call (the dtor.).

So even if someone has a one-pointer solution, it contains the second pointer through some indirection.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution with code examples. The 2 ptr approach makes it clear, the only small downside is generation of one function per type. The shared base class solution is also an option, the only small downside is the types which wouldn't be virtual at all must become virtual with the shared base class. I am not concerned with multiple dereferences on destruction, more with space expense for multiple pointers for every object. In this variant  the only additional cost is one pointer, since the other pointer in the vtable would have to be generated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume a reasonable compiler which puts the dtor last in the vtable. After all, the dtor is rarely called - only once per object. You can't find it because the various vtables have different lengths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This thought experiment seems too flimsy so I will abandon it. I was expecting some kind of guarantee, like the v-table order to be the same as members listed in the source file. But there seems to be no such rules.

Comment: Like here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/391533/c-what-is-the-order-of-function-pointers-inside-vtable

Comment: @gru: the standard doesn't even guarantee the existence of a vtable, let alone it's layout.